# Stream Xbox audio to raspberry pi via Xbox Wireless

Tags: audio, bluetooth, wireless

Is it possible to transfer Xbox Audio to raspberry pi via Xbox Wireless protocol? i.e. using raspberry pi as a Xbox controller.

I need to record in-game chat voice conversations, because for some games (like Fortnite) a voice will be transferred to the controller if something is plugged into the controller, and I can't record it via HDMI output.

Comment: Is this an open protocol? I.e. is the specification available and not encumbered by patents?

Comment: About patents I don't know. About protocol I saw only this: https://gist.github.com/devkid/4b3bd50760504d1b93ea684cfd3ed895

Comment: So it looks like a kind of peer-to-peer wifi.

Comment: So, what do you want to say? It's impossible to do?